# Display Row number using UNIX command

Tags: unix

What Unix command returns row number for all records in a file. Below is the requirement.
id name salary
10 a 1000
20 b 2000
30 c 3000
But I want output like this.
Row_id id name salary
1 10 a 1000
2 20 b 2000
3 30 c 3000
Thanks for your effort in advance.

Comment: `cat -n input.txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
nl script  ##nl number the line
```

or

```
cat -n file ##This will number empty line as well
```

Comment: @jwenting updated answer. So nl is a command which will number the lines in a file, so o/p will be 1 aa \n 2 bb, while cat -n does the same but it will add line number to empty line as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ print FNR " " $0 }' file
```

It will also print the line number.